# Finite automaton in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state-machine, representation, automaton

What is a good way to represent finite automaton in Haskell? How would the data type of it look like?

In our college, automata were defined as a 5-tuple

```
(Q, X, delta, q_0, F)
```

where Q is the set of automaton's states, X is the alphabet (is this part even necessery), delta is the transition function taking 2-tuple from (Q,X) and returning state/-s (in non-deterministic version) and F is the set of accepting/end states.

Most importantly, I'm not sure what type `delta` should have...

Comment: In case of a deterministic automaton, delta could be of the type Q -> X -> Q

In case of a non-deterministic automaton, I would choose something like Q -> X -> [Q]

Comment: What Sven Hager says, and `F` could be implemented as `isEnd :: Q -> Bool`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two basic options:

- An explicit function `delta :: Q -> X -> Q` (or `[Q]` as appropriate) as Sven Hager suggests.
- A map `delta :: Map (Q, X) Q` e.g. using `Data.Map`, or if your states/alphabet can be indexed by ascending numbers `Data.Array` or `Data.Vector`.

Note that these two approaches are essentially equivalent, one can convert from the map version to a function version (this is slightly different due to an extra `Maybe` from the `lookup` call) relatively easily

```
delta_func q x = Data.Map.lookup (q,x) delta_map
```

(Or the appropriately curried version of the look-up function for whatever mapping type you are using.)

---

If you are constructing the automata at compile time (and so know the possible states and can have them encoded as a data type), then using the function version gives you better type safety, as the compiler can verify that you have covered all cases.

If you are constructing the automata at run time (e.g. from user input), then storing `delta` as a map (and possibly doing the function conversion as above) and having an appropriate input validation that guarantees correctness so that `fromJust` is safe (i.e. there is always an entry in the map for any possible `(Q,X)` tuple and so the look-up never fails (never returns `Nothing`)).

Non-deterministic automata work well with the map option, because a failed look-up is the same as having no state to go to, i.e. an empty `[Q]` list, and so there doesn't need to be *any* special handling of the `Maybe` beyond a call to `join . maybeToList` (`join` is from `Data.Monad` and `maybeToList` is from `Data.Maybe`).

---

On a different note, the alphabet is most definitely necessary: it is how the automaton receives input.

Comment: ThanQ very much for great & comprehensive answer :-)

Just 1 more question: when converting regular expression to automaton, what is better way of representing delta? I need to implement operations such as _concatenation_ , _disjunction_ and _iteration_ of automata. It seems to me map is the winner - or am I wrong?

Comment: @mathemage, you can try implementing both and see which you like (I would try the map version first.) Also, if this answer was helpful you, you should vote it up, and if it answers your question, you can indicate it as accepted with the checkmark: [the faq has some more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @mathemage: If you use the Automaton arrow (see my full answer below) then I think you can express those operations in terms of combinator functions.  For example the disjunction would be a function that passes the input to its two argument states and returns a new function that is the disjunction of the two results.

Answer (score 13):

Check out the Control.Arrow.Transformer.Automaton module in the "arrows" package. The type looks like this

```
newtype Automaton a b c = Automaton (a b (c, Automaton a b c))
```

This is a bit confusing because its an arrow transformer. In the simplest case you can write

```
type Auto = Automaton (->)
```

Which uses functions as the underlying arrow. Substituting (->) for "a" in the Automaton definition and using infix notation you can see this is roughly equivalent to:

```
newtype Auto b c = Automaton (b -> (c, Auto b c))
```

In other words an automaton is a function that takes an input and returns a result and a new automaton.

You can use this directly by writing a function for each state that takes an argument and returns the result and the next function.  For instance, here is a state machine to recognise the regexp "a+b" (that is, a series of at least one 'a' followed by a 'b'). (Note: untested code)

```
state1, state2 :: Auto Char Bool
state1 c = if c == 'a' then (False, state2) else (False, state1)
state2 c = case c of
              'a' -> (False, state2)
              'b' -> (True, state1)
              otherwise -> (False, state1)
```

In terms of your original question, Q = {state1, state2}, X = Char, delta is function application, and F is the state transition returning True (rather than having an "accepting state" I've used an output transition with an accepting value).

Alternatively you can use Arrow notation. Automaton is an instance of all the interesting arrow classes, including Loop and Circuit, so you can get access to previous values by using delay. (Note: again, untested code)

```
recognise :: Auto Char Bool
recognise = proc c -> do
   prev <- delay 'x' -< c   -- Doesn't matter what 'x' is, as long as its not 'a'.
   returnA -< (prev == 'a' && c == 'b')
```

The "delay" arrow means that "prev" is equal to the previous value of "c" rather than the current value. You can also get access to your previous output by using "rec".  For instance, here is an arrow that gives you a decaying total over time. (Actually tested in this case)

```
-- | Inputs are accumulated, but decay over time. Input is a (time, value) pair.
-- Output is a pair consisting
-- of the previous output decayed, and the current output.
decay :: (ArrowCircuit a) => NominalDiffTime -> a (UTCTime, Double) (Double, Double)
decay tau = proc (t2,v2) -> do
      rec
         (t1, v1) <- delay (t0, 0) -< (t2, v)
         let 
            dt = fromRational $ toRational $ diffUTCTime t2 t1
            v1a = v1 * exp (negate dt / tau1)
            v = v1a + v2
      returnA -< (v1a, v)
   where
      t0 = UTCTime (ModifiedJulianDay 0) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
      tau1 = fromRational $ toRational tau
```

Note how the input to "delay" includes "v", a value derived from its output. The "rec" clause enables this, so we can build up a feedback loop.